# Fluent UI 2 columns inside text element of dropdown option

Tags: typescript, dropdown, styling, fluent-ui

Is there any way to have two columns inside an dropdown option using fluent ui ?

The Problem is that i would like to style this so single-digit numbers align well to 2-digit or 3-digit numbers:

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW23C.png)

Thats why i thoughjt it would be better to have two columns and align the content with the numbers with "flex-end" and the second one with the text just normaly Any Ideas?

My Code for maping the options:

```
    let mainGroupOptions = Object.keys(dropDownOptions)
        .map(key => {
            return { key, text: dropDownOptions[key].value + " - " + dropDownOptions[key].label, value: dropDownOptions[key].value };
        });
```

Dropdown HTML code:

```
                        <Dropdown
                            label="Hauptgruppe*"
                            options={mainGroupOptions}
                            selectedKey={mainGroupSelected}
                            errorMessage={errors.mainGroup ? "Hauptgruppe erforderlich" : ''}
                            onChange={(e, option) => { setMainGroupSelected(option.key); deleteErrors(errors, errors.mainGroup) }}>
                        </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the option component? It should give you greater control of option formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what the format needs to look like but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction. You should be able to reduce this to a case of adjusting the styles to get what you need.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {
    Dropdown,
    makeStyles,
    Option,
  } from "@fluentui/react-components";

  const useStyles=makeStyles({
    option:{
        width:"1200px",
    },
    left:{
        float:"left",
        textAlign:"right",
        width:"20%",
    },
    right:{
        float:"right",
        textAlign:"left",
        width:"70%",
        marginLeft:"10px"
    },
  });

  let mainGroupOptions = [
    {
      key: '0',
      value:"Allgemeines"
    },
    {
      key: '00',
      value:"IHK-Gesetz und Organisation der Industrie-un..."
    },
    {
      key: '0000',
      value:"Allgemeines"
    },
  ];

export default function FormatOptions(){
    const c=useStyles();
    const {mainGroupSelected, setMainGroupSelected} = useState(0);
    return (
        <Dropdown
            label="Hauptgruppe*"
            selectedKey={mainGroupSelected}
            onChange={(e, option) => { setMainGroupSelected(option.key); deleteErrors(errors, errors.mainGroup) }}
        >
            {mainGroupOptions.map((option)=>(
                <Option key={option.key} >
                    <div className={c.option}>
                        <div className={c.left}>{option.key}</div>
                        <div className={c.right}>{option.value}</div>
                    </div>
                </Option>
            ))}
        </Dropdown>
    );
  }
```